# Apk size: Firebase MLKit includes large native library even if not in use

Tags: android, firebase, apk, firebase-mlkit

I am using Firebase MLKit in my app, like so `FirebaseVision.getInstance().cloudImageLabeler`.

I am only using the cloud versions of it. But when I look at the apk, it includes large native libraries from Firebase, 10Mb in total for 4 architectures. This make up 80% of my app size. They are named `libclassifier_jni.so` for each architecture.

Upon further inspection of the libraries extracted from the apk, using `objdump -d`, I found these are related to on device image labelling. It has symbols like `Java_com_google_android_libraries_vision_visionkit_recognition_classifier_NativeClassifier_initialize`.

I am sure that I am not using anything Firebase ML on device.

How can I remove these libraries and reduce the size of the apk?

The build is of type release and has proguard rules.

Edit:

Relevant dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.0.1'
```

It doesn't make a difference if I update to the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What dependency did you include in your gradle file?

If you are seeing visionkit then you probably are including com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-object-detection-model or an vision internal sdk by accident.

The only dependency you need for cloud image labeling is com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision

Comment: It worked by removing `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:18.0.0'`. So the [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/label-images#before-you-begin) needs some updating?